# Grabbing a list of nodes in a tree?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

How would you go about grabbing a list of nodes from a tree structure that meet a certain criteria using ocaml? Since everything's created anew, there's no saved data structure. Any type of function that tries to return a list could only return one element when it hits a node, not a list.

Comment: A function can have more than one parameter. In particular, you could use a second parameter to keep track of the nodes you've seen so far that you want to return at the end.

Comment: Issue is if you branch down into multiple trees, they each have a different second parameter, and there's no way to join them all together from the root?

Comment: As in, when you get to the leaves of the tree, you have this second parameter that has the nodes you've seen, but you can't just return this for every single leaf, since all of the leaves have to return upwards. So at the root, you need to accumulate all of this, but ocaml doesn't have such a data structure? I don't think lists work-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tree type:

```
type tree = Leaf of int | Node of int * tree * tree
```

Here's a function that returns all the even values from the nodes of a tree:

```
let evens t =
    let rec go sofar = function
    | Leaf k -> if k mod 2 = 0 then k :: sofar else sofar
    | Node (k, lt, rt) ->
         let sofar' = if k mod 2 = 0 then k :: sofar else sofar in
         let sofar'' = go sofar' lt in
         go sofar'' rt
    in
    go [] t
```

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot about passing in an accumulator value. Thanks!